# Shorashim Identifier for Rashi on Tanach

Tags: rashi, translation

I am trying to identify Shorashim from Pesukim and Rashi. Finding the ones from the Pesukim is easy - I use the concordance from alhatorah. But finding the root of words used in Rashi is not always so simple. Do you have any advice?

Comment: Please clarify @Burt.  By "root of words used in Rashi" do you refer to how Rashi defines roots in the words of Tanach or do you mean roots of words within the actual text of Rashi's writings (eg. in the first Rashi on the Chumash when he writes "שֶׁהִיא מִצְוָה רִאשׁוֹנָה שֶׁנִּצְטַוּוּ בָּהּ יִשׂרָאֵל", you would want היא for שֶׁהִיא and צוה for מִצְוָה)?

Comment: @EraserX the actual text in Rashi's writing

Answer (score 1):

This is an old set, but may provide you with what you are looking for. It contains indices verb tables, etc.

https://www.ebay.com/itm/374183394229?mkcid=16&mkevt=1&mkrid=711-127632-2357-0&ssspo=gcO1BBVlT8a&sssrc=2349624&ssuid=mz7vpjlmqb6&var=&widget_ver=artemis&media=MORE

It was first published in the 1980's by the World Zionist Organization in Hebrew and English and authored by Dr. Sampson A Isserhoff under the title, **An Introduction to Rashi's Grammatical Explanations**.

He collected all the explanations of grammar found scattered throughout Rashi's commentaries and published them separately. The original set covered all of Chumash and a few volumes of Nach. If you can find it, it is a surprisingly handy text to help in comprehending the Hebrew language.

What follows is the approbation which was written by Rabbi Ahron Soloveichik in 1990.

[image: Approbation to book]

Answer (score 0):

While the [online version of Mikraos Gedolos HaKeter](https://www.mgketer.org/search) doesn't offer a breakdown of each and every word, you can [search there within meforshim](https://www.mgketer.org/search/perushim) (and select Rashi if you only want Rashi) and when entering search terms, specify that you are searching on a root.